# How do I add multiple lines of text to tabs in Swift Playgrounds?

Tags: swiftui

My app in Swift Playgrounds has tabs. I want to add multiple lines of text to one tab, but I don’t know how. I can’t find an answer anywhere.

```
 Text("Developer").tabItem { Text("Settings").tag(5)
                                        VStack {
                                            Image(systemName: "gear")
                                                .font(.title)
                                            Text("Settings")
                                        }
                                    }
```

I tried it the normal way, but it just spaced out the specific tab more than all of the other tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to specify the text you would like to add, and where you would like to add it. This can work to add more text within the main content area of the tab:

```
TabView {
    VStack {
        Text("Line 1")
        Text("Line 2")
        Text("Line 3")
    }
    .tabItem {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "gear")
                .font(.title)
            Text("Settings")
        }
    }
    .tag(5)

    // ... other tabs ...
}
```